# Loading image gallery slow, how to improve?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, gallery

help you guys,
I have a single that loads a gallery of images (about 32 images and each image with 768x513px), when it arrives at the bottom of the page a request ajax after another 32 (the rest if it has), I'm using ajax and a jquery collage plugins, which Displays images, but loading is slow.
Any idea how to improve it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add what you have tried and review this link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Provide code examples, there's a whole host of reasons why it's slow. Without your code we're just guessing.